# O365\SharePoint rest call on Large list - checked out (recursive)

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, caml, sharepoint-rest-api, large-lists

Wondering if anyone has a suggestion for querying a large list > 5000 items to get all the checked out files (recursively).

*Can I query the search index for this?*

Here's what I've done so far without success on a large list (works for smaller):

**REST**: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=CheckoutUserId/Title&$filter=CheckoutUserId ne null";`

**CAML:**

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser' /></IsNotNull></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
```

Comment: Could you check if it is possible to index the CheckOutUser field in the list settings? In general indexing a field will help you with this issue.

Comment: Its a good suggestion, unfortunately because the list is beyond the limit it throws this error "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator. "

Answer (score 1):

You can do small change to your REST query

**REST Call**

```
/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/Items?$filter=CheckoutUserId ne null&$top=100
```

In the response, if you have more records to match your request it will give link to get the next set of items.

```
<link rel="next" href="siteurl/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/Items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_SortBehavior%3d1%26p_ID%3d850&amp;%24top=10"/>
```

This can see from the browser response and from JavaScript you get from `data.d` object.

You can repeat the calls until this value null/undefined/empty.

Comment: Appreciate the info but I think its still stuck on the threshold.. For some reason even simple queries are returning "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Comment: This has been tested. Can You give me your query?